# Must all US public companies have an investor relations website?

Tags: united-states, stocks, financial-statements, websites, news

Are all US public companies required to maintain a website where they publish press releases and financial statements? If so, do such requirements only apply to exchange-listed companies, or are OTC stocks subject to such requirements too? I am asking because I want to know whether or not an investor relations website is guaranteed to exist for any given US public company.

Comment: I doubt that a company is required to have a website in the first place...

Comment: @JonCuster All companies listed on some Euronext stock exchanges such as Amsterdam, Brussels, Dublin, Lisbon, and Paris are required to have a website. Just wondering if there are similar regulations in the US.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

I am pretty darn sure that the only requirements to be a publicly traded company is that said company meets all the standards to be public traded and files the necessary forms correctly and on-time with the Securities and Exchange Commission, which will then make those forms publicly available.

http://www.legalandcompliance.com/securities-resources/sec-requirements-for-public-companies/

There is not legal requirement that a company maintains an investor relations webpage or I think even have an investor relations department.